# What could be causing my "error checking push permissions" error on GitLab CI using Kaniko?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, kaniko, gitlab-pipelines

I am running dockerized GitLab CI 13.8.3, and recently I have been getting a new error when trying to build and push a docker image (via Kaniko) to my registry. The pipeline has been working for months now for this project, and I have not changed my docker-compose or gitlab-ci.yml files. The error and excerpt from my gitlab-ci.yml are below. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Error:

```
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: 
checking push permission for "xxxx:5005/xxx/kotlin-starter:": 
creating push check transport for xxxx:5005 failed: Get "https://xxxx:5005/v2/": dial tcp xxxx:5005: i/o timeout
```

Here is the applicable section from my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
build:
  stage: package
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - |
      echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      mycertishere
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----" >> /kaniko/ssl/certs/additional-ca-cert-bundle.crt
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

Comment: did you find any workaround for this